# Java memory management mystery

Tags: java, xml, memory-management

I have this piece of code inside a static method of a Java program:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
...
Document tempdoc1=tempdoc;
//tempdoc1=xmlModifier.setMacro(tempdoc, liquidity, "liquidity"); // this slightly modifies the document
tempdoc1=null;
if (tempdoc1==null){
tempdoc1=tempdoc;
} 
...do something with tempdoc1
```

What I don't understand is the following: if I take out the comment "//" I get a different result from the subsequent execution of the code, while from my basic understanding it should be exactly the same, since in any case the variable tempdoc1 is redefined at the following line! Does anybody know why?

EDIT: I don't see how the static method setMacro of the class xmlModifier can modify the object referenced by tempdoc. For example this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test="test";
    String test2=dosomething(test);     
    System.out.println(test);

}

public static String dosomething(String str){
    str="mod";
    return str;
}
```

simply prints "test", i.e. the method dosomething does not modify the object referenced by test. Are there situations where this is not the case?

Comment: What do you mean, when you say "I get a different result"? What result do you expect? What result do you obtain?

Comment: it means that the xml document tempdoc1 is different in the twu cases (the method setMacro actually modifies a part of the tree)

Answer (score 1):

Well presumably the statement:

```
xmlModifier.setMacro(tempdoc, liquidity, "liquidity");
```

has some effect on `xmlModifier`, or `tempdoc`, or `liquidity` - so with that commented out, you don't see that effect.

My *guess* is that the method modifies `tempdoc` and then returns it, and you're expecting it to return a copy. Objects in Java don't work that way. In fact, it wouldn't modify `tempdoc` at all - it would modify the object that the value of `tempdoc` refers to. If the method returns a reference to the same object, that doesn't create a new object - it just means you've got two references to one object, like two pieces of paper each with the same house address on.